# wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to handle commands with pipes like `ls | wc` or `ls /tmp | wc -l` but i am getting the "wc: standard input: Bad file descriptor" message. It's my first time working on something like that. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        char *cmd, *splitcmd, *splinput, *splipip;
        int i, j, nargc = 0, characters;
        char **cmdArray;
        char **splArray;
        char **pipArray;
        size_t bufsize = 1024;
        int *pipefd;
        int pipeArrCount;
        pid_t pid, wpid;
        int status = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int metro = 0;
        char pr1[40],  pr2[40],  pr0[40];
        char pi0[40],  pi1[40],  pi2[40];
        char pip0[40],  pip1[40],  pip2[40];
        int savestdoutfd = dup(fileno(stdout));
        int savestdinfd = dup(fileno(stdin));

        char *path;
        path = getenv("PATH");

        cmd = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
        characters = getline(&cmd, &bufsize, stdin);
        printf("cmd == => %s  characters == =>  %d \n", cmd, characters);
        if (cmd[characters-1] == '\n')
        {
            cmd[characters-1]='\0';
            characters--;
        }
        printf("cmd == => %s  characters == =>  %d \n", cmd, characters);

        cmdArray = (char**)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *) );
        for (i = 0; i < bufsize; i++ )
        {
            cmdArray[i]=(char*)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char ) );
        }

        splitcmd = strtok(cmd, "|");
        printf(" cmd ==  ==   %s\n", cmd);
        while((splitcmd))
        {
            strcpy(cmdArray[nargc], splitcmd);
            if (cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1] == ' ')
                cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1]='\0';
            printf(" nargc ==  == %d  cmdArray == =[  %s  ] \n", nargc, cmdArray[nargc]);
            nargc++;
            splitcmd = strtok(NULL, "|");
        }

        strcpy(pr0, cmdArray[0]);
        strcpy(pr1, cmdArray[1]);
        strcpy(pr2, cmdArray[2]);
        printf(" pr0  %s   \n", pr0);
        printf(" pr1  %s   \n", pr1);
        printf(" pr2  %s   \n", pr2);

        splArray = (char**)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *) );
        for (i = 0; i < bufsize; i++ )
        {
            splArray[i]=(char*)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char ) );
        }

        splinput = strtok(pr0, " ");
        while((splinput))
        {
            strcpy(splArray[count], splinput);
            if (splArray[count][(strlen(splArray[count]))-1] == ' ')
                splArray[count][(strlen(splArray[count]))-1]='\0';
            printf(" count ==  == %d  splArray == =[  %s  ] \n", count, splArray[count]);
            count++;
            splinput = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }


        strcpy(pi0, splArray[0]);
        strcpy(pi1, splArray[1]);
        strcpy(pi2, splArray[2]);
        printf(" pi0  %s   \n", pi0);
        printf(" pi1  %s   \n", pi1);
        printf(" pi2  %s   \n", pi2);

        pipArray= (char**)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *) );
        for (i = 0; i < bufsize; i++ )
        {
            pipArray[i]=(char*)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char ) );
        }

        splipip = strtok(pr1, " ");
        while((splipip))
        {
            strcpy(pipArray[metro], splipip);
            if (pipArray[metro][(strlen(pipArray[metro]))-1] == ' ')
                pipArray[metro][(strlen(pipArray[metro]))-1]='\0';
            printf(" metro ==  == %d  pipArray == =[  %s  ]    \n", metro, pipArray[metro]);

            metro++;
            splipip = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }


        strcpy(pip0, pipArray[0]);
        strcpy(pip1, pipArray[1]);
        strcpy(pip2, pipArray[2]);
        printf(" pip0  %s   \n", pip0);
        printf(" pip1  %s   \n", pip1);
        printf(" pip2  %s   \n", pip2);

        pipefd=(int*)malloc(2 * nargc*sizeof(int));
        printf(" nargc == =   %d\n", nargc);
        pipeArrCount = 2*(nargc-1);
        printf("pipeArrCount == = %d\n", pipeArrCount);
        //exit(0);
        for(i = 0; i < pipeArrCount; i)
        {
            pipe(pipefd + i);
            i = i + 2;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < nargc; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if ((pid = fork())  ==  0)
                {
                    dup2(pipefd[2 * i+1], fileno(stdout));

                    for(j = 0; j < pipeArrCount; j++)
                    {
                        close(pipefd[j]);
                    }

                    if (count  == 1 )
                    {

                        char *argv[] = {path, NULL};
                        execvp(pi0, argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);
                    }

                    else if (count == 2)
                    {
                        char *argv[] = {pi0, pi1, NULL};
                        execvp(pi0, argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        char *argv[] = {pi0, pi1, pi2, NULL};

                        execvp(argv[0], argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < bufsize; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);

                    }
                    exit(0);

                }
                wait(&status);

                dup2(savestdoutfd, fileno(stdout));

            }

            else
            {
                if (fork()  ==  0)
                {
                    dup2(pipefd[2 * i-1], fileno(stdin));

                    for(j = 0; j < pipeArrCount; j++)
                    {
                        close(pipefd[j]);
                    }
                    dup2(savestdoutfd, fileno(stdout));
                    close(savestdoutfd);
                    if (metro  == 1 )
                    {

                        char *argv[] = {pip0, NULL};
                        execvp(pip0, argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);

                    }

                    else if (metro == 2)
                    {
                        char *argv[] = {pip0, pip1, NULL};
                        execvp(argv[0], argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        char *argv[] = {pip0, pip1, pip2, NULL};
                        execvp(argv[0], argv);
                        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        {
                            free(cmdArray[i]);
                        }
                        free(cmdArray);
                    }
                    dup2(savestdinfd, fileno(stdin));
                    close(savestdinfd);
                    exit(0);

                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < pipeArrCount; j++)
        {
            close(pipefd[j]);
        }
        while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the freeing activity after the `execvp()` calls are problematic, not because of what they `free()` but because the only time they're executed is when the `execvp()` fails — but when that happens, the child should probably report an error on standard error and exit, rather than go back to the main loop and prompt for more input.  Note that your main input code doesn't consider the possibility that `getline()` might return `-1` to indicate no more data; when it does, you go poking around memory before the start of your arrays, and other dubious practices.  You need to use functions!

Comment: My compiler tells me that the line `for(i = 0; i < pipeArrCount; i)` has a bug: `ms.c:126:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]` (though the body of the loop includes `i = i + 2;`). If your compiler isn't telling you about such things, you need to fix your compilation options until it does — or get a better compiler. (GCC 5.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.1, compiling with: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror ms.c -o ms`. It also warns about signed vs unsigned comparisons in various loops.)

Comment: Your code is using pseudo-arrays like `pi0`, `pi1`, `pi2`, and `pip0`, `pip1`, `pip2`, and `pr0`, `pr1`, `pr2`.  They make life hard; use real arrays.  They also make the code fragile.  And long-winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is operator precedence — probably.  In the `else` clause for the `for` loop that runs the commands in a pipeline, you have:

```
dup2(pipefd[2 * i-1], fileno(stdin));
```

That spacing on the subscript calculation is odd; the code is equivalent to:

```
dup2(pipefd[2*i - 1], fileno(stdin));
```

However, that descriptor is the write descriptor of the pipe, not the read descriptor, so `wc` gets `EBADF` when it tries to read from a write-only file descriptor.

What works is:

```
dup2(pipefd[2 *(i-1)], fileno(stdin));
```

You should be using `STDIN_FILENO` instead of `fileno(stdin)`, and similarly `STDOUT_FILENO`.

There are many other issues that should be resolved, but this will get you going.